# Computing 1- or 2- Wasserstein distance between collections of point masses

Tags: optimal-transport

Is either $W_1$ or $W_2$ (the Wasserstein distances) available in closed form when comparing two collections of point masses?

To be specific, let $p = \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{x_i}$ and $q = \sum_{j=1}^m \delta_{y_j}$ for two arbitrary sets of points $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n, \{y_j\}_{j=1}^m\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$.
For  $d = 1$ or $2$, could one compute either $W_1(p, q)$ or $W_2(p, q)$ efficiently?

Comment: No closed form, but equivalent to min-cost flow between bipartite graphs.

Comment: @dohmatob Thanks. I could only find a reference for $W_1$; could you point me to some references for $W_2$?

Comment: The Sinkhorn iteration (Cuturi 2013) is pretty much the SOTA: https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.0895